# Get Rendered Form into $StateChangeStart

Tags: angularjs, forms

Is there any way that I can get the rendered form into

$rootScope.on("$stateChangeStart", function (){

})

I tried two things.
First: Using $template Request I got the template using templateURL and compiled that but it renders predefined template not the DOM's rendered.

See the code

```
if (fromState.name.length > 0) {
  $templateRequest(fromState.templateUrl)
    .then(function (html) {
       var compiledElement = $compile(html)($rootScope);
       var compliedForm = compiledElement.find('form');
    }
}
```

then Secondly, I tried using

```
angular.element('document').find('form');
```

But it gives me list of attribute and all. But how to get check form is valid or not.

Document

[image]

Comment: `angular.element('document').find('form').controller("form").$valid;` But I think the real question here is what are you trying to achieve? It looks like you are trying to do something in a non-angular way

Comment: This *feels like* an [XY Question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/297619).  It's not obvious at all what you are trying to accomplish, or why you would need the rendered form.

Comment: @devqon,
I want to check the form is valid or not on stateChange. If form is not valid then I want to show popup message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are trying to achieve, is to block a state change when a form in the current view is not valid. I would make a directive for this, something like:

```
app.directive("formValidStateCheck", function($rootScope) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        require: "ngForm",
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngFormCtrl) {
            $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function(event) {
                if (ngFormCtrl.$invalid) {
                    // prevent routing
                    if (!confirm("Are you sure"))
                        event.preventDefault();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Than put the directive on your forms:

```
<form ng-form="myForm" form-valid-state-check>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

`.find()` method will not work with selectors and tag names. you need to get it by form id(for this have a id to the form).

Then use `angular.element(document.getElementById("#form_id"));`